# Exportar arquivo .SAP no R

Tags: python, r, erp

Seria possivel exportar um arquivo em .SAP utilizando R ou Python ?

Encontre um tutorial que dizia que no R para exportar em .SAP seria da seguinte forma:

```
write_sas(df, "table.sas7bdat")
```

Porém fiquei com uma duvida, quando faço essa extração o final do arquivo fica realmente com a extensão ".sas7bat", só que em outro sistema que exporta em .SAP ele fica com a extensão .SAP

Comment: A extensão é a que você colocar no nome do arquivo que está criando. Se mudar `"table.sas7bdat"` para  `"table.sap` vai resolver.

Comment: então eu posso simplesmente mudar o final da extensão que da certo?

Comment: Não seria um arquivo .SAS?

Comment: Pode haver bug nesse pacote, veja os comentários dessa questão: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52031042/r-export-to-sas-but-cannot-open.

Comment: @RafaelBarros então a extensão que eu preciso é .SAP

Answer (score 2):

O pacote [haven](/questions/tagged/haven) disponibiliza duas formas de exportar arquivo para o `SAS` no  `R`. Estas duas formas estão empacotadas nas funções [`write_sas()`](https://haven.tidyverse.org/reference/read_sas.html) e [`write_xpt()`](https://haven.tidyverse.org/reference/read_xpt.html). Você pode ler na documentação delas qual forma é mais adequada às suas necessidades.

Qualquer arquivo que você gerar com essas funções poderá ser lido no SAS, ***INDEPENDENTE DO SEU NOME (E PORTANTO EXTENSÃO)***

O `SAS` será capaz de ler arquivos com a extensão errada (desde que seja de fato um arquivo para ser lido pelo `SAS`).

```
library(haven)  
td <- tempdir()
# Arquivo com extensao errada
write_sas(mtcars, paste0(td, "/iris.xlsx"))
read_sas(paste0(td, "/iris.xlsx"))
#> # A tibble: 32 x 11
#>      mpg   cyl  disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec    vs    am  gear  carb
#>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#>  1  21       6  160    110  3.9   2.62  16.5     0     1     4     4
#>  2  21       6  160    110  3.9   2.88  17.0     0     1     4     4
#>  3  22.8     4  108     93  3.85  2.32  18.6     1     1     4     1
#>  4  21.4     6  258    110  3.08  3.22  19.4     1     0     3     1
#>  5  18.7     8  360    175  3.15  3.44  17.0     0     0     3     2
#>  6  18.1     6  225    105  2.76  3.46  20.2     1     0     3     1
#>  7  14.3     8  360    245  3.21  3.57  15.8     0     0     3     4
#>  8  24.4     4  147.    62  3.69  3.19  20       1     0     4     2
#>  9  22.8     4  141.    95  3.92  3.15  22.9     1     0     4     2
#> 10  19.2     6  168.   123  3.92  3.44  18.3     1     0     4     4
#> # ... with 22 more rows
```

O `SAS` também será capaz de ler arquivos sem extensão:

```
# Arquivo sem extensao 
write_sas(mtcars, paste0(td, "/sem_extensao"))
read_sas(paste0(td, "/sem_extensao"))
#> # A tibble: 32 x 11
#>      mpg   cyl  disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec    vs    am  gear  carb
#>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#>  1  21       6  160    110  3.9   2.62  16.5     0     1     4     4
#>  2  21       6  160    110  3.9   2.88  17.0     0     1     4     4
#>  3  22.8     4  108     93  3.85  2.32  18.6     1     1     4     1
#>  4  21.4     6  258    110  3.08  3.22  19.4     1     0     3     1
#>  5  18.7     8  360    175  3.15  3.44  17.0     0     0     3     2
#>  6  18.1     6  225    105  2.76  3.46  20.2     1     0     3     1
#>  7  14.3     8  360    245  3.21  3.57  15.8     0     0     3     4
#>  8  24.4     4  147.    62  3.69  3.19  20       1     0     4     2
#>  9  22.8     4  141.    95  3.92  3.15  22.9     1     0     4     2
#> 10  19.2     6  168.   123  3.92  3.44  18.3     1     0     4     4
#> # ... with 22 more rows
```

E até com a extensão correta:

```
# O mesmo serve para as funções *_xpt
write_xpt(mtcars, paste0(td, "/mtcars.xpt"))
read_xpt(paste0(td, "/mtcars.xpt"))
#> # A tibble: 32 x 11
#>      mpg   cyl  disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec    vs    am  gear  carb
#>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#>  1  21       6  160    110  3.9   2.62  16.5     0     1     4     4
#>  2  21       6  160    110  3.9   2.88  17.0     0     1     4     4
#>  3  22.8     4  108     93  3.85  2.32  18.6     1     1     4     1
#>  4  21.4     6  258    110  3.08  3.22  19.4     1     0     3     1
#>  5  18.7     8  360    175  3.15  3.44  17.0     0     0     3     2
#>  6  18.1     6  225    105  2.76  3.46  20.2     1     0     3     1
#>  7  14.3     8  360    245  3.21  3.57  15.8     0     0     3     4
#>  8  24.4     4  147.    62  3.69  3.19  20       1     0     4     2
#>  9  22.8     4  141.    95  3.92  3.15  22.9     1     0     4     2
#> 10  19.2     6  168.   123  3.92  3.44  18.3     1     0     4     4
#> # ... with 22 more rows
Created on 2019-02-22 by the reprex package (v0.2.1)
```

#### Nota sobre extensões

A extensão de um arquivo ajuda a entender o formato daquele arquivo, mas ela só ajuda e está pensada basicamente para humanos.

Programas costumam usar outros métodos para verificar como ler aquele arquivo. Uma delas, não sei se a única ou mesmo a mais utilizada, é ter uma número mágico da extensão. Mais informações sobre número mágico podem ser encontradas [aqui](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_signatures).

No windows a extensão do arquivo é como o sistema operacional decide qual programa usará para abrir o arquivo **por padrão**, mas você pode escolher outro na mão caso queira ou ele não saiba qual usar.

Comment: então, minha duvida é: a extensão que eu preciso é .SAP e nao SAS, será que isso interfere ?

Comment: Salve um arquivo pelo SAS e descubra a extensão padrão usada. Ela fara diferença só para você. O SAS será capaz de ler o arquivo independente da sua decisão

Comment: então, oq acontece eu vou mandar esse arquivo para uma pessoa que utiliza o .SAP, SAS não entra em momento algum na relação desses arquivos, por isso minha duvidas, eu realmente preciso que o arquivo seja .SAP e não SAS

Comment: Tem certeza que se trata de um arquivo ".SAP"? Só achei essa extensão relacionada com [música](https://fileinfo.com/extension/sap)